# Setting Media query with 3 break points

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

I am using Bootstrap for responsive website. according to the business i require to keep only 3 break points with fluid layout. as like :

```
1024px and above = 4 column
768px - 1024 px = 2 column
below 768px = 1 column
```

at present i have the html as :

```css
div.col-lg-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But how to set to fix with my business requirement? any one help me?

Comment: first of all `bootstrap-4` doesnt support `col-xs*`

Comment: you can use `col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3` and if you are using `scss` change breakpoint lg to 1024 from 992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the bootstrap source code, you can create your own custom column class for these breakpoints with the proper media queries.

```css
.col-custom {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .col-custom {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1024px){
  .col-custom{
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-custom">1</div>
    <div class="col-custom">2</div>
    <div class="col-custom">3</div>
    <div class="col-custom">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```